# How can I copy the formula used in a cell to another cell as a literal formula

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, spreadsheet

Cell A1 has the value 1.
Cell A2 has the value 2.
Cell A3 has the formula entered " = A1 + A2" and shows the value 3.
Similarly Columns B1,B2, B3,  C1, C2, C3 etc.. etc..

I want to copy the formula (in A3, B3 etc) into cells A4, B4 etc such that A4 reads  "A1 + A2", B4 reads "B1 + B2" etc.
Can this be done ?

Perhaps the request appears odd, but only because I have simplified my project to show the essence of the problem. I need to do this to check for repetitive entry, if any of the same expression, say A1 or A2 or C3, in more than one formula.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using:

```
=A1 + A2
```

use:

```
=$A$1 + $A$2
```

this will copy without adjustment.

Comment: I need cell A4 to read:  A1 + A2

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way is to use absolute references as in @Gary's Student's answer.  But if you do not want to change the original formulas, then there are other workarounds.

One clever way is to copy a whole range of addresses by first removing the equals sign using Find and Replace (or by replacing with `a=` as suggested [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8925/how-can-i-copy-paste-calc-formulas-with-absolute-references/)).  Then copy and paste, and finally change it back to `=`.  This is illustrated in Method 3 at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/01/20/copy-formula-excel/#copy-formula-without-changing-references

What I have used in the past is the following key sequence:

1. Edit the formula: <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Select the formula: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
3. Copy the formula: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
4. Exit the formula: <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Now paste the unchanged formula.

If this is something that you need to do often, it may be worth setting up a macro like this one, which does steps 1-3.

```vb
Sub CopyLiteralFormula
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SetInputMode", "", 0, Array())
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SelectAll", "", 0, Array())
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())
End Sub
```

I played around with it for a few minutes but couldn't get it to do step 4 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1) Select `A3:C3`,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

2) Select `A4`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

3) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

4) Select `A5`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

[image]

5) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

6) Select `A4`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

After that, `A4:C4` is the same as `A3:C3`,
And we can clean `A5:C5`, if needed:

[image]